# Anyone build a "Outlook Social Connector" for SO? (perhaps integrated Soapi.CS/C#)

Tags: discussion, app-request, soapi.cs

I'd like to see an [Outlook Social plugin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee829696.aspx) that shows the reputation of [everyone](https://stackapps.com/questions/1542/how-do-i-find-a-user-based-upon-email-hash) on a given email message.

**Update**: [Here](http://socialsetup.codeplex.com) is a sample project to get started.  80% of the work is now complete...

It would also be nice to see a feed of most current questions the user has asked.

Has anyone built something like this?

Here is an example of the Linkedin connector, showing you the LinkedIn profile of anyone who is included on the related email message.

[image]